# ROS Answers SE migration: six module

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello ; i have a problem during executing this command in the terminal """ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte """ the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/rosws", line 52, in <module> import rosinstall.rosws_cli File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/__init__.py", line 33, in <module> import wstool.helpers File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/helpers.py", line 37, in <module> from wstool.config_elements import SetupConfigElement File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/config_elements.py", line 38, in <module> from vcstools.vcs_abstraction import get_vcs_client File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools/__init__.py", line 44, in <module> from vcstools.svn import SvnClient File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools/svn.py", line 44, in <module> import dateutil.parser # For parsing date strings File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 24, in <module> from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types ImportError: No module named six
```

plz ; how can i fix this error ????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156486/six-module/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-22

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are missing the six python library which should be available from your package manager. Note you are also using vcstools from source or pip which is not recommended except for developers with specific needs other than using the tool

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0